# Q: Regional disparity OR regional disparities between 31 counties of a country

Tags: grammar

There are differences in health care provision between 31 counties of a country. We would like to conclude that there is a regional disparity in health care in that country. Which of the following sentences is correct?

Regional dispari**ty** in health care provision in Country

OR

Regional disparit**ies** in health care provision in Country

Comment: I think the plural sounds better.

Comment: Yes; the disparities will be of varying degrees, and the plural points to this.

Comment: If you are talking about a disparity between one of those countries and the level of provision in the other thirty than **disparity** would be appropriate. It might even work if two or more countries had reasonably similar low levels of provision but the all the rest had vastly superior provision. However with such a large study group you are more likely to find several spectra of provision with significant discrepancies between most of them so I'd go with the plural.